# Keep color output when running scripts on composer

Tags: php, composer-php, bdd

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) allow running scripts, as said in [defining scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#defining-scripts).

So, I'm trying to run some spec tests with it.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./vendor/davedevelopment/dspec/bin/dspec"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "esperance/esperance": "dev-master",
        "davedevelopment/dspec": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

It runs fine, but there is no color output, and for spec tests this difficults the reading.

How can I run the scripts but keep the original colored output?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the `--ansi` param.

```
"test": "./vendor/davedevelopment/dspec/bin/dspec --ansi"
```

Answer (score 2):

The davedevelopment/dspec library uses the symfony/console component. Symfony/console uses the **POSIX extension** to determine whether to allow color output. If you want color to show up by default without passing the `--ansi` flag, you just need to install the POSIX extension.

Comment: `php -m|grep posix` shows POSIX is installed here, but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just run phpunit via composer and the colors are there. Perhaps the `dspec` script has no color support or is disabled by default.

```
"scripts" : {
  "test" : "./vendor/bin/phpunit -c tests/phpunit.xml"
},
```

Comment: Maybe some singularity of `dspec` then. I'll take a deeper look.

Comment: I have problems with PHPUnit outputting colors through Composer. I've tried various ways to call it, but no luck so far. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: I added `--colors=always` from PHPUnit master (4.6) branch which did the trick. It seems PHPUnit actually detects it is called through another scripts and suppresses the colors itself.

Comment: On Windows 10, I have colors enabled in my phpunit.xml, and normally this does enable colors, but when run with composer, the colors are gone.

Comment: I got it working with --colors=always. This is from my "scripts" section in composer.json `"test": "phpunit --colors=always"`. Composer automatically knows to look in vendor/bin for this phpunit (since it is not in my PATH, and I add it per project). It is also using the default phpunit.xml at my project root. @HaralanDobrev also mentoined --colors=always, but the way they mentioned master confused me into thinking they were doing something other than adding that to their command to run phpunit.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 at the time of my comment (2015) this flag from PHPUnit wasn't released in a stable version and I've tried the latest PHPUnit development from their master branch.